# How to re-create an OpenShift route from cli without yaml?

Tags: gitlab, openshift

I created an Openshift route with the oc cli through my GitLab pipeline with:

`oc create route edge --service=... --cert=... --key=... --ca-cert=... --hostname=...`

When the pipeline runs again, I get an error that the route already exists. How can I re-create the route or skip this step in the GitLab pipeline so that I dont get the error?

I already tried with oc replace and oc apply, but I guess I then need to use a yaml and I dont want to hardcode the tls parameters in the yaml.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried with oc replace and oc apply, but I guess I then need to use a yaml and I dont want to hardcode the tls parameters in the yaml.

Have your `oc create` command output a YAML manifest rather than directly applying the changes, and then use `oc apply` to apply the manifest:

```
oc create route edge \
  --service=... --cert=... --key=... --ca-cert=... --dry-run=client -o yaml |
  oc apply -f-
```

You don't need to hardcode your manifest, *and* you get the `oc apply` semantics so you won't get an error if the resource already exists.